# Not allowed to include a default constructor - Java Basics

Tags: java

Class A:

```
public class A {    

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A{

    private int billNum;

    B(String firstName, String billNum) {
        super(firstName);
        setBillNum(billNum);

    }

    public int getBillNumr() {
        return billNum;
    }

    public void setBillNum(int billNum) {
        this.billNum = billNum;
    }
```

1.) Now i want to add a default **like** constructor like `B() {}`, but i am not allowed to do so. Why is this ?

Comment: What problem are you getting? Did you put a `super` call in that, to explicitly invoke the `1-arg constructor` of `A class`, in case you don't have any `0-arg constructor` in `A-Class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the subclass constructor you call a one-argument superclass constructor, which you didn't declare. Add `A(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }` to the superclass. Alternatively, replace the line `super(firstName);` with `setFirstName(firstName);` in the constructor of B.

Comment: I added a constructor that takes 1 parameter to class A. Now you want me to replace `super(firstName);` with `setFirstName(firstName);` ? I get this error when i try to do so `Implicit super constructor A() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Comment: Note the key word "alternatively". It means do either one **or** the other, but don't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

The code you've provided won't compile, due to this line in B:

```
super(firstName);
```

That suggests that *actually*, your `A` class has a constructor like this:

```
public A(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

At that point, trying to declare a new constructor in `B` will fail without a `super` call, because there isn't a parameterless constructor in `A`.

So this will work:

```
B() {
  super("Anonymous");
}
```

*Or* you could add a parameterless constructor to A:

```
A() {
  this("Anonymous");
}
```

... at which point you can just use `B() {}` in B.

Basically, once you understand that a constructor without any explicit `this(...)` or `super(...)` call is equivalent to calling `super()` (i.e. a parameterless constructor in the superclass) it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't have an constructor in class a which takes a string as an argument and you are trying to call super(first name) from ur subclass constructor.

```
class A{
String firstName;
public aA(String firstname){
this.firstName= firstName;
}
}
```